# How can I prove that a polynomial has no rational roots?

Tags: calculus

Let say I have a polynomial with n as the maximum degree.

Say: $a_1x^n+a_2x^{n-1}+...+a_n$

How can I prove that it does not have any rational roots?

For example: If we have polynomial with degree 2, We can determine it has no roots if $b^2-4ac<0$, But when the degree is higher than 2 what can we do?

Comment: If $n$ is odd it will definitely have a real root. Only if $n$ is even is it possible for there to be no real roots.

Comment: Since OP mentioned the condition $b^2-4ac<0$ as a condition for no roots, I assumed he meant real roots.

Comment: Sorry, I meant rational roots.

Comment: Just a little comment on your notation, if you really want to start with $a_1 x^n$, then the last term should be $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383186/find-a-solution-of-the-polynomial

may be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the [rational root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_test). This test states that if an integer-coefficient polynomial $f(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0$ has a rational root $r = p/q$ and the root is  in *lowest terms*, i.e. $\gcd(p,q)=1,$ then it follows that $$ q\mid a_n,\ \ p\mid a_0.$$ Other things we can do include [Eisenstein's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_criterion), which will show that the polynomial is irreducible, hence doesn't have a root, or we can also use modular arithmetic. If we look at the polynomial in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ for some prime, is it irreducible? If the answer is yes, then the poly. is irreducible over the integers, too.

Comment: What do you mean by "For $n$" ?

Comment: Nice Clayton. +1

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is odd it will definitely have a real root. Only if $n$ is even is it possible for there to be no real roots.

One method when $n$ is even is to determine the points of minima of the polynomial $p(x)$ using calculus. If $a_1>0$ and the minima of $p$ are greater than zero, then $p$ cannot have any roots.

**EDIT:** For testing of integer roots, take a look at the [rational root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_test).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i meant integer roots. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @TheAlchemist, then **edit your post** in addition to apologizing.